# Planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query at Connection

Tags: mongodb

I haven't use the `$geoNear` in my query instead I have used `$nearSphere`. But this is showing the error of `$geoNear`. And the error creates the interruption in processing the query. Not always but once in every hour or maybe in 12 hours approx.

**I'm using `Mongoose`**

**I have deployed the project at `Heroku`**

I have used `2dsphere` index already.

```
scheduleRideSchema.index({ source: '2dsphere' });
```

My Query :

```
const source_match = await Trip.find({
    $or: [
        {
            $and: [
                { pickupStart: { $gte: pickupStartTime }}, 
                { pickupEnd: { $lte: pickupStartTime }}
            ]
        },
        {
            $and: [
                { pickupStart: { $gte: pickupStartTime }}, 
                { pickupEnd: { $lte: pickupEndTime }}
            ]
        },
        {
            $and: [
                { pickupStart: { $lte: pickupStartTime }}, 
                { pickupEnd: { $gte: pickupStartTime }}
            ]
        }.
        {
            $and: [
                { pickupStart: { $lte: pickupStartTime }}, 
                { pickupEnd: { $gte: pickupEndTime }}
            ]
        }
    ],
    source: {
        $nearSphere: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: sourceCord.coordinates
            },
            $maxDistance: 4000
        }
    },
    cancel: false,
    complete: false
});
```

Error:

> error processing query: ns=UpdatedJaza.tripsTree: $and $or $and
>   pickupEnd $lte new Date(1563352260000) pickupStart $gte new
>   Date(1563352260000) $and pickupEnd $lte new Date(1563355860000)
>   pickupStart $gte new Date(1563352260000) $and pickupStart $lte new
>   Date(1563352260000) pickupEnd $gte new Date(1563352260000) $and
>   pickupStart $lte new Date(1563352260000) pickupEnd $gte new
>   Date(1563355860000) cancel $eq false complete $eq false GEONEAR
>   field=source maxdist=4000 isNearSphere=0 Sort: {} Proj: {} planner
>   **> returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query'**